# Algorithm for transforming contour to 2D bool array

Tags: algorithm

I want to create 2D array representing geometric shape given by contour (list of edges).
The shape can always be split into rectangular primitives and lays on grid (like in notebook with squared paper) . My goal is to create 2D bool array which represent the grid and which fields are: true - if grid cell is inside the contour ( is part of the shape ) or false otherwise. Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this ? I spent hours on this and still have nothing.

Comment: Consider the centre of each cell in your grid to be a point and search for *point in polygon* methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let left(row, column) be true iff the cell at (row, column) has an edge on its left border (this is easy to calculate from the list of edges). Then:

```
for each row
    inside = false
    for each column
        if (left(row, column) == true)
            inside = !inside
        isInside[row, column] = inside
```

`isInside` is your bool grid. This algorithm completely ignores the horizontal edges and makes the assumption that the shape is closed (so "inside" and "outside" have meaning). If the shape is not closed, then the results are meaningless, as there is no inside and outside.

This is optimal (as it is linear with the size of the output).

Comment: I don't understand how you can define this as optimal? If we have an `n = 1000 x 1000` 'world' and a `k = 1 x 1` region then with your `O(n)` solution you would need `n = 1M` iterations just to fill a single pixel? I would define optimality much more as a function of `k`...

Comment: If you have a 1000 x 1000 grid then you need 1 million steps to output 1 million values even if you just always output false and don't do any calculations. Yes if you want to know the "true" or "false" value of just 1 point in the grid, it is not optimal. But that is not how I understand the question. As I read it, the polygon is a subset of the grid.

Comment: I agree, but the grid could already be initialized or you may want to draw multiple regions in a sequence...

Comment: If you mean initializing the grid once, then drawing many small polygons to the same grid, avoiding going through the whole grid each time, that is simple, you just go from min(x) to max(x) for columns and min(y) to max(y) (min and max of current polygoon vertex coordinates) for rows instead of 0...N, 0...M. And instead of setting true or false, OR with the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Put edges in two sorted lists  - vertical edges, sorted by X, and horizontal edges, sorted by Y-coordinate.

Find any cell inside the contour  - for example, near bottom end of the leftmost edge.

Then start [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) from this cell. Check for borders in vertical list when moving left-right, and in horiz. list  when moving up-down (using binary search).